# Turtle Beachs Not Picking Up TV Audio

Tags: xbox-360, audio-hardware

I just bought these brand new turtle beaches and I want to play xbox with them. I have the audio jacks (greed / pink into red / white jack extender) but I have an HD LED TV with Digital Surround Sound. I'm pretty sure it gets it's sound from fiber wire into the main speakers so I'm unsure what to do with the red / white audio jacks. We have no other audio jacks plugged in and the TV still plays audio (so it must be from this clear wire).

First I thought I could just plug in my audio cables from my headphones into the respected jacks of the TV - then change my system preferences to Digital Stereo but still nothing has happened. Any suggestions would be helpful!!

In "Preferences -> Voice ->" I have it set up to play both game audio and voice audio through headset.

**Additional Info**

- My Xbox hooks up to my TV via a single HDMI cable.
- Turtle Beach Model is X12
- I hook my Turtle Beaches to my Xbox via USB.
- The Turtle Beaches have additional cords (green / pink to an extender red / white)

Comment: Could you specify your Turtle Beach model? Also, how do you currently hook up your xbox to your TV? HDMI? Component? Do you hook it directly to the TV or through an amp/receiver?

Comment: I've updated my question. So far I've gotten nothing on the other places I've asked this question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, your basic problem is your connection hookup. Here's what you need to do.

(Note: All images below are from [the X12's manual (PDF)](http://www.turtlebeach.com/support/file/1112/))

- Hook up your headphones to the x360 via USB, this provides power for the headphones. Now, connect the green X12 connection to an Xbox 360 Audio Adapter connected to your system via the red/white. Alternatively, you can connect the green cable to your TV headhones/audio out port (make sure the TV's setting have the audio outputted to these connections.

[image: X12's hooking diagram from the manual]

- If you wish to use the headset for chat as well, connect the talkback cable between the headset and the X12's amplifier and set the system settings like the following image.
  [image]

Comment: Yeah, in the end what I needed was the HDMI Audio Adapter Cable.